# Applying n-grams and TF-IDF using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have been trying to migrate a code I have written in scikit-learn using [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). the scikit-learn API is very useful because let you choose the granularity of your n-grams (word or char level).
Essentially I have a list of `name` and I want to create a `name` classification model.

I want to accomplish 2 steps using TensorFlow:

1. Apply n-grams extraction at char level to the name list. `Example with range 2: Alan Smith will be `['Al', 'la', 'an', 'n ', ' S', 'Sm', 'mi', 'it', 'th']`.
2. Apply TF-IDF based on the vocabulary generated above.

I have tried to use [ngrams](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/ngrams) but seems like the only option is to use n-grams at word level.
Any insights how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the input itself to character level using list comprehension:

```
x = 'Alan Smith'

[[b for b in a] for a in x.split()]

Out: [['A', 'l', 'a', 'n'], ['S', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h']]
```

Then use your ngrams function on that input or build the ngrams manually like here:

```
ngrams = [[''.join(b) for b in zip(a,a[1:])] for a in x.split()]

Out: [['Al', 'la', 'an'], ['Sm', 'mi', 'it', 'th']]
```